# Is it ok to specify the extern keyword in both defintion and declaration

Tags: c++

I know that the `extern` keyword in C++ can be used to tell the compiler that the specific variable has an external linkage (it is defined in another translation unit):

```
// first.cpp

int foo = 0;

// second.cpp

extern int foo;
```

But what about the following usage?

```
// first.cpp

extern int foo = 0;

// second.cpp

extern int foo;
```

Note that both files have the `extern` keyword specified for the same variable in both definition and declaration.

Is it ok? If so, what's the difference then?

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/) the C standard specifies *"if a variable is only declared and an initializer is also provided with that declaration, then the memory for that variable will be allocated i.e. that variable will be considered as defined"*. Also, the compiler throws errors if you try to add another definition of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extern int foo = 0;
```

is the same as

```
int foo = 0;
```

for all practical purposes. The `extern` keyword is redundant but not incorrect.

However, there is a difference between

```
extern int foo;
```

and

```
int foo;
```

The first one is a declaration while the second one is a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `extern` does not inform the compiler that the definition of `foo` is in another translation unit. All it does it declare its existence.

So `foo` can be declared many times. But it can only be initialised once.

Hence in your particular case, your writing `extern int foo = 0;` is equivalent to `int foo = 0;`